# Is there a word for people you like but are a pain in the ass?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

Is there a word for people you like but are a pain in the ass? Nothing too vulgar. I am not looking to call someone it, but affectionately think about them "that person is a complete [word]". It's for a friend (of the opposite sex, though I don't necessarily want to signal that here).

- oh God Debbie, can you stop being a [word]

I was thinking of 'frienemy' but that may be the opposite. I was also thinking of 'difficult' but it's potentially offensive and patronizing.

Comment: What's an "EL word"?

Comment: english language @Laurel ?

Comment: Can you go through the [checklist here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) and edit in more detail for the rest of your question?

Comment: i can delete if you think it would be better @Laurel ?

Comment: If you go through [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) checklist and [edit] those details into your question, it would be _way_ better than deleting it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to help you with your question here. I still think you need more details about the situation you want to use this in. For example, the words we'd use for a boss that won't let you be lazy are different from the words we'd use to describe a child who's acting like a child.

Comment: ok thanks that's helpful @Laurel maybe the question isn't helpful

Comment: It's all about context and inflection. If you call someone who trusts you an *asshole* with a smile on your face it can be a fitting answer to this question. Say it to someone you don't know or with a sneer, and you might end up in a fistfight.

Comment: If you want to be tactful, you can say they are an acquired taste :)

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

> That person is a complete **wind-up**.
> Oh God Debbie, can you stop being a **wind-up**?

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wind-up) has

> **wind-up**
> <sup>*noun*</sup>
> something that is not true that you tell someone in order to make a joke:
> *You can't be serious - is this a wind-up?*

This doesn't really cover the noun description of a person (nor does Merriam-Webster) but
[Chambers Dictionary](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=wind-up&title=21st) has

> **wind-up**
> <sup>*noun*</sup>
> the taunting or teasing of someone, eg the playing of a practical joke on them.

It is usually a deliberate ploy or joke, but the other party may not realise how annoying their behaviour is, and saying it this way implies they know what they are doing.